# How to show a button on specific webpages with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user goes to my website and clicks on an article from the main articles page, I would like the "Back to Articles" button to only show up on those subpages. How do I specify those articles under the articles folder? Can I use a wildcard *.html to get all html pages under the articles folder in the pathname? I'm new to javascript.  Thanks!

Here's the code I have:

```
--HTML5

<a href="../articles/articles.html" class="btnArticles">Back to Articles</a>

--CSS3

.btnArticles {
    background-color: #BA6222;
    color: #ffffff!important;
    border-radius: 90px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #E49135;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    float:right;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 90px;  
    display:none;

}

.btnArticles:hover {
    background-color: #BA6222;
    opacity: .8;
    color: #E7E7E7!important;
}

--JS

//Articles button show/hide only on html pages under the articles folder

$(document).ready(function(){

    if (window.location.pathname == "[href='nameofsite/articles/*.html']"){
        $(".btnArticles").show();
    }
        else
        {
            $(".btnArticles").hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: At the very least show us what the URLs would look like, pages on which the button should show, and pages on which it should not. Also, bear in mind that showing/hiding the button with JavaScript isn't secure (depending the reason for showing/hiding) since it's still present in the HTML. This should really  be done server-side, with [tag:ruby], [tag:php], [tag:asp], [tag:.net] etc.

Comment: I agree with you. I'm also learning asp.net and will have to update the site with server-side scripts in the near future.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, show buttons if it's under /articles folder, but not /articles/articles.html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.pathname.match(/\/articles/)
   && (! window.location.pathname.match(/\/articles\/articles\.html/)))
  {
    $(".btnArticles").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $(".btnArticles").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  your suggestion slightly worked.  The button doesn't show on the articles main page, but shows on every page including the sub articles.  I just need them to show on the sub articles.  here's my client's site so you can see what I mean nav to the articles link: henriwtartt.com

Comment: @user2923855, we shall find a minimal solution that fixes your need to run as quickly as possible by the browser.

Comment: I really appreciate it. I'll be fiddling with it myself and post if I get it working.

Comment: I'm almost there...it only shows up on the articles main pg and it's sub pg's without showing on any of the others.  Now I just have to get it off the articles main pg.


$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.pathname.match(/articles\/*.*\.html/))
  {
    $(".btnArticles").show();
  }
  else 
  {
    $(".btnArticles").hide();
   }
});

Comment: Great! That worked! the AND operator definitely did the trick.  It makes perfect sence.  Thank you jacouh.